# Can I use Visual Studio for ONLY C?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm already a lpt familiar with MS VS

So if I can learn C with it, then it'd be great!
But I read VS doesn't support latest C versions anymore!

Can I use VS (maybe with Intel Compiler) for only C?

Comment: If you want to use standard C (which would be C11) you should be careful and verify they **really** support it. MS has notoriously refused to support C99, but **claimed** they want to support C11 (which would likely include C99), but not sure if they already (and completely) do. But why not use a smaller and more understandable IDE like Code::Blocks and a standard-compliant compiler like gcc or clang?

Comment: The problem with Code::Blocks is, I don't like the interface a bit! Though I like eclipse but its annoying autocomplete feature is pissing me off! I have to press CTRL+ Space every single time to bring it up!

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: @jessehouwing  I'm confusing C++ with C a lot! Is C++11 has all the standard libraries of C11?

Comment: Install Linux and use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and some editor like `emacs` (and some builder like GNU  `make`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm already in linux and using GCC with Eclipse! But I don't like text editors anyway :)